# Saving form value to model Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

Hello I'm very new to Ruby, but I'm tasked to program ruby on rails web. Here I have a folder welcome which have "welcome_controller" and "register.html.erb" page.

I also have model called user. Here I have form in my register page

```
<%= form_tag do %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:username,nil,placeholder:"username") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:password,nil,placeholder:"password") %
   <%= text_field_tag(:fullname,nil,placeholder:"full name") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:birthplace,nil,placeholder:"place of birth") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:birthdate,nil,placeholder:"date of birth dd-mm-yyyy") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:city,nil,placeholder:"city") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:hobby,nil,placeholder:"hobby") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:gender,nil,placeholder:"gender (M/F)") %>
   <input type="button" value="Sign Up">
<% end %>
```

When the button clicked, I want to save all fields value as the attributes of user (model). I don't know what I have to make in the controller and the model since I'm very new to Ruby. Please kindly help me thank you.

I don't want to make a specific page for every model because I have to make 1 page to be able save data for many model.

NB : I'm using Ruby (1.9.3) on rails (4.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

The RailsGuides are a very valuable resource, follow the 'Getting Started with Rails' guide. It runs through what you are wanting to achieve from creating the model, controller, and view. The guide starts from scratch so it is very easy to follow. You'll be able to save your user data after completing it.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Hopefully this resource solves your issue.